# Cannot get Sailfish contacts with QContactManager

Tags: c++, qt, sailfish-os

I try to get Jolla's (SailfishOS) phonebook contacts from QContactManager.

```
QContactManager *manager = new QContactManager();
QList<QContact> results = manager->contacts();
```

*results* list contains 0 contact. 

I check also if there is error:

```
QContactManager::Error error;
```

QContactManager's error code is *NoError*.

Then I check available managers.

```
manager->availableManagers()
```

- org.nemomobile.contacts.sqlite
- invalid
- memory

  `QContactManager *manager = new QContactManager();`

  `QContactManager *manager = new`

  `QContactManager("org.nemomobile.contacts.sqlite");`

In both case: manager no error, but manager->managerName() result is *invalid*.

On the other hand, if I create manager as:

```
QContactManager *manager = new QContactManager("memory");
```

... I can use this memory based `QContactManager` (for example save and get contacts) normally.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking.  What have you tried?  What doesn't work?  Show some code.  More information would be helpful.

Comment: I just edited more information and examples to my original question.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://lists.sailfishos.org/pipermail/devel/2014-January/003042.html) is relevant to what you're trying to do.